# Regular Expression in URL php

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I have the following code for deciding what default controller to use with codeigniter.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="5409.gs.mycoolurl.org") {

   $route['default_controller'] = 'new-site/newsite'; 
}
else {

   $route['default_controller'] = '';
}
```

The problem is that in `5409.gs.` the `5409` will be random but always 4 digits long. How do I allow any 4 digit numbers and the .gs into this if statement? I have tried:

`[0-9].gs.mycoolurl.org` but always got the `else` side of things.

Comment: `.` in regex means "match anything (except newline if the `s` modifier ins't set)". Basically you need to escape it `\.` or put it in a character class `[.]`. If you've got that `[0-9]` will match a digit then it's just a matter of adding a quantifier. Think about `+`, `{1,4}`, `{4}` etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (preg_match("/\d{4}\.gs/", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {

$route['default_controller'] = 'new-site/newsite';
```

EXPLANATION

```
\d{4} match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: Exactly 4 times
\. matches the character . literally
gs matches the characters gs literally (case sensitive)
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! I will accept this answer in 4 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

`\d{4}.gs`

\d is for digits

{4} is a range of 4

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: I still end up at the `else` side of things. :(

Comment: You should escape the dot.

Comment: Update answer please. As it is not solving the question.